# Table Design New

Tags: database-design

Here is my Dataframe

| ABC | Date | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/22 | 1 |
| A | 1/2/22 | 2 |
| B | 1/1/22 | 3 |
| B | 1/2/22 | 4 |

Expected Output

| Date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/22 | 1 | 3 |
| 1/2/22 | 2 | 4 |

Please revert how i can achieve the expected output

Answer (score -1):

You may use pivoting logic here:

```sql
SELECT Date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ABC = 'A' THEN Data END) AS A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ABC = 'B' THEN Data END) AS B
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Date;
```

Comment: @Subhendu That sounds like a good topic for another question.